# Passing variables with localStorage.setItem using java, json, ajax and html

Tags: java, html, json, ajax

I am trying to use localStorage to pass variables between pages. In the java I populate a List:

```
output.add(0, accountGroup.getAccountId());
output.add(1, accountGroup.getLevel());
output.add(2, accountGroup.getGroupName());
output.add(3, "0");
output.add(4, accountGroup.getGroupSection());
output.add(5, accountGroup.getGroupNAS());
output.add(6, nextView);

String json = new Gson().toJson(output);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(json);
```

And then I try to store each variable in the ajax:

```
.done(function(responseJson){
                dataType: "json";    
                localStorage.setItem('lsAccountID', $('#temp').val(responseJson[0]));
                alert(localStorage.getItem('lsAccountID'));
                localStorage.setItem('lsAccountLevel', $('#temp').val(responseJson[1]));
                localStorage.setItem('lsGroupName', $('#temp').val(responseJson[2]));
                localStorage.setItem('lsNoGroupsStarted', $('#temp').val(responseJson[3]));
                localStorage.setItem('lsGroupSection', $('#temp').val(responseJson[4]));
                localStorage.setItem('lsGroupNAS', $('#temp').val(responseJson[5]));
                localStorage.setItem('lsNextView', $('#temp').val(responseJson[6]));

                window.location.assign("SelectPerson.html");
})
```

This is not storing the correct value ("7" in this case) this is shown by "alert(localStorage.getItem('lsAccountID'));" returning "[object Object]" instead of "7". I know that "7" is being stored by "output.add(0, accountGroup.getAccountId());" by adding a "System.out.println".

Comment: Don’t `alert` stuff to debug. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and use `console.log`.

Comment: Why is this required?

Comment: If you want to see more details than `[object Object]` like the _actual contents of that object_, then `console.log` would be the best way to do so.

Comment: Hi Xufox, the log is the following, which I believe does not equate to to this issue: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: null</ul>
    at Function.fa.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at fa.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.fa [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new n.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at n (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (selectPerson-ajax.js:29)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)

Comment: Interesting that people down vote without providing comments. I suppose they do not know the answer either.

Comment: People are downvoting because no specific problem statement was provided. “This is not working” isn’t helpful at all.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use parseJSON:

```
       .done(function(responseJson){
            dataType: "json";    
            var result = $.parseJSON(responseJson);

            localStorage.setItem('lsAccountID', result[0]);
            localStorage.setItem('lsAccountLevel', result[1]);
            localStorage.setItem('lsGroupName', result[2]);
            localStorage.setItem('lsNoGroupsStarted', result[3]);
            localStorage.setItem('lsGroupSection', result[4]);
            localStorage.setItem('lsGroupNAS', result[5]);
            localStorage.setItem('lsNextView', result[6]);

            if(result[6] == "1"){
                window.location.assign("SelectPerson.html");
            }else{
                $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(result[6]);
                $("#accountName").focus();
            }
            window.location.assign("SelectPerson.html");
        })
```